# In Python's sqlite3 module, why can't cursor.rowcount() tell me the number of rows returned by a select statement

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

So I've read [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount) and it says:

> Cursor.rowcount¶
>
> Although the Cursor class of the
>   sqlite3 module implements this
>   attribute, the database engine’s own
>   support for the determination of “rows
>   affected”/”rows selected” is quirky.
>
> This includes SELECT statements
>   because we cannot determine the number
>   of rows a query produced until all
>   rows were fetched.

How come, immediately after executing a SELECT, I can't use this to determine the number of rows returned. Surely the query, having been executed, has now fetched all the rows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQLite does not "fetch" all the rows when initially processing the query. It returns a single row each time the prepared query is stepped.

From the SQLite3 FAQ [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWikiFaq)

Q) Which func could get the number of rows?

A) There is no function to retrieve the number of rows in a result set. SQLite doesn't know the number in advance, but returns row by row while iterating through the tables. The application can increment a row counter as needed at every successful sqlite3_step() .

Some wrappers are able to collect all rows in a resultset in a in-memory table, so they can return the number of rows.

You can always get the number of rows that a certain SELECT statement would return at the cost of some performance:

```
BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM x WHERE y;
SELECT a,b,c FROM x WHERE y;
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

You have to wrap this in a transaction to prevent other connections from inserting / deleting rows between the two SELECT statements.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer, that made it a lot clearer what is going on, and told me exactly what I should be doing.