# cursor.rowcount gives 'int' object is not callable error

Tags: python

i selected values from sqlite3 database and print the count of cursor.then it gives an error " 'int' object is not callable"

```
strq="select * from tblsample1"
self.con = sqlite3.connect('mydb.sqlite')
self.cur = self.con.cursor()
self.cur.execute(strq)              
print(self.cur.rowcount())
```

gives an error

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: but it give -1 in all situations

Comment: I personally find your communication  style, especially the habit of posting the same comment on each answer, very annoying. Instead of guessing what `rowcount` could mean, why don't you follow the link on the corresponding Python documentation everybody here is giving you?  It explains what `rowcount` is supposed to represent and why it might be `-1`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Read [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount) carefully! rowcount is an attribute so correct your code to:

```
 print(self.cur.rowcount)
```

> Cursor.rowcount Although the Cursor
>   class of the sqlite3 module implements
>   this attribute, the database engine’s
>   own support for the determination of
>   “rows affected”/”rows selected” is
>   quirky.

---

> This includes SELECT statements
>   because we cannot determine the number
>   of rows a query produced until all
>   rows were fetched.

---

So you can modify your code to use [fetchall](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=sqlite3#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall):

```
self.cur.execute(strq) 
data = self.cur.fetchall()
print len(data)
```

Comment: but it give -1 in all situations

Comment: As per python documentation: 'As required by the Python DB API Spec, the rowcount attribute “is -1 in case no executeXX() has been performed on the cursor or the rowcount of the last operation is not determinable by the interface”.'

Comment: what is meant by executeXX()?what is the solution? __Thank You__

Comment: I have modified my answer. executeXX is execute/executemany/executescript. Anyway it will always returns you -1 in case you will try to use rowcount after executing select statement. It will be better to call fetchall and then simply use len

Comment: cannot update using __self.cur.execute(strupdatequery)__ why?

Comment: It is always better to ask one question per one thread. Anyway try to look at http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=sqlite3#sqlite3.Connection.commit

Comment: You are not ever calling `cur.fetchall()` here, so the literal code, as written, produces a type error. And why fetch all rows just to use `len()` on the list? That's just a waste of resources. Use `SELECT COUNT(*)` to have the server do the counting.

Answer (score 12):

```
print(self.cur.rowcount)
```

`self.cur.rowcount` is an integer, not a function.

http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount

**Edit**

The documentation answers your edit:

> As required by the Python DB API Spec, the rowcount attribute “is -1 in case no executeXX() has been performed on the cursor or the rowcount of the last operation is not determinable by the interface”.
>
> This includes SELECT statements because we cannot determine the number of rows a query produced until all rows were fetched.

Comment: but it give -1 in all situations

Comment: what is meant by executeXX()?what is the solution? __Thank You__

Comment: @KIRAN SQLite doesn't know the rowcount in advance. You can find a workaround here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911404/in-pythons-sqlite3-module-why-cant-cursor-rowcount-tell-me-the-number-of-row

Comment: cannot update using __self.cur.execute(strupdatequery)__ why?

Comment: @KIRAN: There are multiple possible reasons.  Invalid SQL, no such table, file permissions, ...  If you are stuck, consider posting a new question and give detailed information on what you are trying to do, what error message you get and what's in the variables you are using.

Comment: that is not an error.now i got the answer `connection.commit()` __Thank You Very much__

Comment: @KIRANKJ -- don't you mean `cur.commit()` ?  ("cur" not "con".)  Other people who find your question want to know your solution!  Are you saying you did `execute` then `commit` on a `select`?  (Instead of a `fetch`??)  And then `cur.rowcount` gave correct #s?

Answer (score 3):

The error message says it all really. Don't call the `rowcount` value, just access it:

```
print(self.cur.rowcount)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strq="select count(*) from tblsample1"
self.con = sqlite3.connect('mydb.sqlite')
self.cur = self.con.cursor()
rows = self.cur.execute(strq)              
print(row)
```